# how do i get the return value from a bpel boolean variable?

Tags: web-services, bpel

I am new to BPEL. I am invoking a web service to fill a BPEL variable:

```
<bpel:variable name="hasASkillOutput" messageType="ns2:personHasSkillResponse"></bpel:variable>
....
<bpel:invoke name="call_personHasASkill"  partnerLink="SkillPossessionService"  operation="personHasSkill"  portType="ns2:SkillPossessionServicePortType"
                inputVariable="hasASkillInput" outputVariable="hasASkillOutput"></bpel:invoke>
```

The service that I invoke returns a boolean. How can I access that value as part of a condition expression?

```
        <bpel:if name="DoesPersonHaveTheSkill">
                <bpel:condition><hasASkillOutput is true></bpel:condition>
        </bpel:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the messageType `personHasSkillResponse` is defined in the WSDL that is linked by your partnerLink `SkillPossessionService`. You you have to look up that structure there and then you can use an ordinary XPath 1.0 expression in your `condition` and reference the variable `hasASkillOutput`.

If for example your message type definition looks like this:

```
<message name="personHasSkillResponse">
    <part name="skillResponse" element="xsd:boolean"/>
</message>
```

Your condition would have to look like this:

```
    <bpel:if name="DoesPersonHaveTheSkill">
            <bpel:condition>$hasASkillOutput.skillResponse</bpel:condition>
    </bpel:if>
```